# App Constantly Crashes Owing To The java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android

Basically, I have been trying to make a sort of timer app. The user has to sets the time and presses a button to run a timer. When he presses the button, one ConstraintLayout becomes invisible while a timer ConstraintLayout becomes visible and the timer starts to run.

The problem is, whenever I press the button, the app crashes and it shows the following message:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method updateTimer(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'startTimerButton'

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.theaccountabilityproject;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public EditText setTimeEditText;

    public TextView timerTextView;
    public TextView endTimerTextView;

    public Button startTimerButton;

    public ConstraintLayout preTimerConstraintLayout;
    public ConstraintLayout timerConstraintLayout;
    public ConstraintLayout postTimerConstraintLayout;

    int totalDuration;

    //Method for converting time in milliseconds to minutes and seconds in mm:ss format for textView
    public void timeConverter(long remainingTime){

        long minutes = remainingTime / 60;
        remainingTime = remainingTime % 60;

        long seconds = remainingTime;

        String minuteString = String.valueOf(minutes);
        String secondString = String.valueOf(seconds);

        if (minutes <= 9)
            minuteString = "0".concat(minuteString);

        if (seconds <= 9)
            secondString = "0".concat(secondString);

        String totalTime = minuteString.concat(" : ".concat(secondString));
        timerTextView.setText(totalTime);

    }

    //Timer method
    public void updateTimer(View view){

        preTimerConstraintLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        timerConstraintLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        totalDuration = Integer.parseInt(setTimeEditText.getText().toString());
        totalDuration = totalDuration * 60 * 1000;

        new CountDownTimer(totalDuration, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                long timeInSeconds =  millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                timeConverter(timeInSeconds);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                timerConstraintLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                postTimerConstraintLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);

        setTimeEditText = findViewById(R.id.setTimeEditText);
        timerTextView = findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);
        endTimerTextView = findViewById(R.id.postTimerTextView);

        startTimerButton = findViewById(R.id.startTimerButton);

        preTimerConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.preTimerConstraintLayout);
        timerConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.timerConstraintLayout);
        postTimerConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.postTimerConstraintLayout);

    }

}
```

Here's the layout file as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TimerActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/preTimerConstraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/setTimeTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:text="@string/setTimeTextView"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="@font/varela_round"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/setTimeEditText"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/setTimeTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/varela_round"
            android:hint="@string/minuteHint"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startTimerButton"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/biorhyme_bold"
            android:text="@string/done"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/setTimeEditText"
            android:onClick="updateTimer"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/timerConstraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/motivationalMessageTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:text="@string/motivationalMessageTextView"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/varela_round"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timerTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/motivationalMessageTextView"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_alternates_bold"
            android:text="@string/sampleTimer"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="60sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stopTimerButton"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/timerTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="@string/StopTimer"
            android:fontFamily="@font/biorhyme_bold"
            android:elevation="50dp"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/postTimerConstraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/postTimerTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:text="@string/accountabilityString"
            android:fontFamily="@font/varela_round"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/endTimerTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/postTimerTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="@string/endTimerString"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_alternates_bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="60sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/postTimerButton"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/endTimerTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="50dp"
            android:text="@string/letsgo"
            android:fontFamily="@font/biorhyme_bold"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I looked at a few other answers but was still was unable to figure it out.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I would not use the old form of `android:onClick` in a modern Android app. In your case, you can call `setOnClickListener()` on the `startTimerButton` in your `onCreate()` function, after you call `findViewById()` to get that button.

Comment: I'm still quite new at this and I haven't yet kept in touch with all that's happening. But could you tell me why it doesn't work anymore? I mean, a few weeks before I was working on another project and the on:Click didn't cause any problem back then.

Comment: "But could you tell me why it doesn't work anymore?" -- it requires that the method be implemented on the hosting `Activity` and implies that the `LayoutInflater` that inflates the layout is tied to that `Activity`. Since the advent of fragments in 2011, we often need more flexibility and control. To be honest, I have not seen anyone use `android:onClick` in years, except when using data binding and a data binding expression.

Comment: "a few weeks before I was working on another project and the on:Click didn't cause any problem back then" -- then you can try to determine what the differences are between the projects and adjust your newer project as needed. Personally, I would simply not use `android:onClick`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help.